# How to use Xcode to detect double release of object?

Tags: xcode, release, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've got a MFMailComposeViewController object that I'm releasing in my Email button's callback, simply because I created it, and I think my doing so is intermittently but not always crashing my app.

How can I use Xcode's instrumentation program to detect such a situation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `NSZombieEnabled` environment variable to `YES` (*Product > Edit Scheme…*, the select *Run (Product Name)*, click the *Arguments* tab and edit the list of environment variables). With `NSZombie`, objects will not be deallocated but turned into zombies. Messaging them will log an error to the console instead of crashing with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. That way you can find out if it’s really the `MFMailComposeViewController` that’s causing trouble.

But retaining and releasing the view controller might not even be necessary. If you present the `MFMailComposeViewController` immediately after creating it and don’t use it anymore after it’s been dismissed, there’s no need to retain it:

```
- (IBAction)composeMessage:(id)sender {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposeViewController = [[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    mailComposeViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [self presentModalViewController:mailComposeViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)mailComposeViewController didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
    // Present error to the user if failed
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```